# kvm cpu0 disabled perfctr wrmsr - hangs

Tags: centos-6, linux-kvm, libvirt

I initially asked this question on StackOverflow, but it was marked as off-topic and said I might get help here.. so here it is

==============

I am currently running Centos 6.5, and tried to follow the instructions to install a VM with a Centos 5.5 Dvd1.iso file, but after running the setup for the VM, I do an installation in "text mode", it says "ready.kvm" but after that it seems to hang after a while.

[image]

The previous screenshot shows it hanging after I do the "virsh console XXX". Am I doing something wrong? Are the cpu0 disabled messages normal?

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The command I ran to install the VM is as follows:

```
virt-install --network bridge:br0 --name VM_NAME --ram=32768 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/kvm-images/VM-image.img,size=20 --graphics=none --cdrom /kvm-images/CentOS-5.5-x86_64-bin-DVD-1of2.iso
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out what the problem was. The original host linux I was installing on, was accessed via KVM and it did not have a desktop (GNOME) installed.

When CentOS tries to do the installation, it tries to access the graphics card, in this case, it was not set.

So I had to setup X11Forwarding on my Windows PC by setting up XMing and using Putty, I SSHed into the host server. When setup correctly, it will create a .Xauthority file

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

When I type `xterm` it will bring up a terminal window. From there, I did the `virt-install` command, and everything works (despite the mouse being laggy)..

Hope this helps anyone else with this problem~!